# What ROM will turn my Verizon HTC One M8 into the same thing as the unlocked dev version?

Tags: rom, htc-one-x, verizon

I have an HTC One (M8) from Verizon, but I don't live in the US.  I'd like to find a ROM that will make my phone have the same settings as the unlocked Dev Version that you can buy directly from HTC.

I tried searching the XDA forums, but I do not understand most of the features described by the various roms, and they all seem to use code names and jargon.  Which ROM will just give me a simple clean install as if I had bought the unlocked dev version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2706441) looks like what you want. Basically, any ROM that says it's a "GPe" rom or a "Google Play edition" rom will be what you're after. To get the Google Apps you'll need to flash a GApps package such as the [ParanoidAndroid ones](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2397942) - you can just choose the "stock" package. Flash those after flashing the ROM and you'll have a pre-rooted, dev version ROM.

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that I won't get updates when new versions of the OS come out? I'll have to find roms and download them again?

Comment: @avi yep you'll get a notification of an update but you can't install it. You need to install a new  ROM each time. It's... tedious.